# Break Out of Do-Until Loop IF Select-String is Discovered

Tags: powershell

There are two conditions:

1. if Pattern "Idle" is found then send found email
2. if the its more than 60 minutes of run time send email not found

Both cases need to finish the email and job is complete.
The Pattern is discovered and the email is going out - but it continues to loop.
I tried the  {break} to exit the loop - but that's not happening and the loop continues.

```
$File =  "AutoDE45oService_AP.$(get-date -Format yyMMdd).log" 
#setup loop
$TimeStart = Get-Date
$TimeEnd = $timeStart.addminutes(60)

Do { 
#get the Idle as sign of completion 
if (Get-Content $File -Tail 1 | Select-string -Pattern "Idle" -Quiet) {
                $Subject = "Test - MHC AutoDE AP completed at $(Get-Date)" 
                $Body = "IDLE FOUND" 
                Send-MailMessage -smtpserver "$SMTPServer" -from "$EmailFrom" -to "$EmailTo" -subject "$Subject" -bodyAsHtml "$Body" -credential $anonCredentials
                #{break}
                 }
 else {
                 $TimeNow = Get-Date
 if ($TimeNow -ge $TimeEnd) {
                 $runtime = 'Duration: {0:mm} min {0:ss} sec' -f ($TimeNow-$TimeStart)
                 $Subject = "Test - MHC AutoDE AP incomplete after $runtime at $(Get-Date)" 
                 $Body = "PROBLEM TO REPORT" 
                 Send-MailMessage -smtpserver "$SMTPServer" -from "$EmailFrom" -to "$EmailTo" -subject "$Subject" -bodyAsHtml "$Body" -credential $anonCredentials
                 }

 }
 Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
}
Until ($TimeNow -ge $TimeEnd)
```

Comment: I believe `-Quiet` will return `$true` at first appearance of the string, so the break the `do loop` part of your question is already answered

Answer (score 0):

I added some comments to help you with the logic. Basically, you are asking PowerShell to do 2 things at the same time, and unless my logic is completely wrong, this is not possible on one thread. This is why you need to use a runspace / job.

```
$elapsedTime = [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()

$job = Start-Job {
    # Note: $file should be the absolute path of your file
    Get-Content $File -Raw | Select-string -Pattern "Idle" -Quiet
}

while($true)
{
    # if the job has completed
    if($job.State -eq 'Completed')
    {
        $result = $job|Receive-Job

        # if result is True
        if($result)
        {
            $elapsedTime.Stop()
            $duration = $elapsedTime.Elapsed.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
            
            # .... send email logic here
            # for success result

            break #=> This is important, don't remove it
        }

        # we don't need a else here,
        # if we are here is because $result is false
        
        $elapsedTime.Stop()
        $duration = $elapsedTime.Elapsed.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")

        # .... send email logic here
        # for unsuccessful result
        
        break #=> This is important, don't remove it
    }

    # if this is running for more than
    # 60 minutes break the loop
    if($elapsedTime.Elapsed.Minutes -ge 60)
    {
        $elapsedTime.Stop()
        $duration = $elapsedTime.Elapsed.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
        
        # .... send email logic here
        # for script running longer 
        # than 60 minutes

        break #=> This is important, don't remove it
    }
    
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
}

Get-Job|Remove-Job
```